# handling negative infinite numbers in pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a file that contains large number of negative infinite numbers (-np.inf) and I've tried every solution I can think of to delete or replace them with 0.

Here is what the data looks like.

```
        id     kind            value    time

    0   1   tmx2005-01  -3.402823e+38   01
    1   1   tmx2005-02  -3.402823e+38   02
    2   1   tmx2005-03  -3.402823e+38   03
    3   1   tmx2005-04  -3.402823e+38   04
    4   1   tmx2005-05  -3.402823e+38   05
```

As you can see, the infinite numbers are under the 'value' column and some of the solutions I tried are:

```
df2.dropna()

df2.fillna(0, inplace=True)

df2.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0).dropna(subset=["value"], how="all")

df2['value'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)

df2['value']=df2['value'].mask(-np.isinf(df2['value']))

df2['value'][-np.isinf(df2['value'])] =0
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong or why its not working?

Comment: I don't see any `-np.inf` numbers in your data. Just very negative ones.

Comment: they're not actual np.inf, they're just really large

Comment: Those values are the most negative values that can be represented with 32 bit floating point; check out `np.finfo(np.float32).min`.  How did those values end up in your file?

Comment: what comes out of running your code is = -3.4028235e+38.  The values are generated from a raster (pixel) file converted into a data frame. Others have pointed out that this could be a large negative number but this doesn't make since the data is about temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in `value` column are not `np.inf` or `-np.inf`. Since you want to remove those very large values you can try this. Here you can use `df.value[0]` as your value which needs to be replaced. First replacing with 0:

```
df.replace(df.value[0], 0)
```

The Output looks like this:

```
    id  kind    value   time
0   1   tmx2005-01  0.0 1
1   1   tmx2005-02  0.0 2
2   1   tmx2005-03  0.0 3
3   1   tmx2005-04  0.0 4
4   1   tmx2005-05  0.0 5
```

If you want to replace it with `np.nan` value then:

```
df.replace(df.value[0], np.nan)
```

Remove the null values using `value` column as a subset:

```
df.dropna(subset=["value"], how="all")
```

Comment: awesome! this seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, The values in your "value" column are not negatively infinite.

It wouldn't make sense to treat them like infinite numbers anyways, as they are many orders of magnitude away from the lower limit of floats in Python, which is around 2e+308.

As a solution, I would choose a value under which you would consider something to be negatively infinite. Here's a pythonic way to do that:

```
limit = -3.402823*10**38
df2['value'] = np.array([0 if value <= limit else value for value in df2['value'])
```

Comment: *"... the lower limit of floats in Python, which is around 2e+308"*  Actually, `-3.4028235e+38` is the most negative value that can be represented with 32 bit floating point; check out `np.finfo(np.float32).min`.